# Private information (not shown publicly) -> they are... aren't they?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, privacy

Under "Edit Profile & Settings" on the bottom in "Private information (not shown publicly)", I entered my full Name for SO job's related stuff, I thought this might be useful. After joining my current companies group on careers and having been displayed on the "Who you will be working with" list, I realized that part is displaying my "Full name" instead of my "Display name".

Is this intended? If so, one should be informed about it since that's not what I would understand by *not shown publicly*, that this information will be displayed along with my current employer and my display name.

If not so, <del>is it only the owner seeing his own full name displayed and everyone else gets shown the display name? Or</del><sup>1</sup> is this something that should be fixed?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>HR just sent me an screenshot to happily inform me being linked now, where I can see, my full name is also being displayed for others</sub>

Comment: Interesting, yes, if that section uses full names then I'd consider that quite a breach of the implied privacy of that field.

Comment: I've looked at a few company pages, and indeed, the Full Name field is used (easily confirmed by looking at the public info on the profile linked). Either the information in the profile editor needs to be re-evaluated, or *and this is the preferable option*, the display name should be used on the jobs site.

Comment: Facebook "privacy" settings come to mind.

Answer (score 15):

Company Pages have used your full name since their inception. Unfortunately we didn't re-evaluate that in context of developer story and the copy indicating the privacy of your real name.

In developer story land this is clearly a bug. [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31280/alex-warren) just fixed it to always use the display name and pushed to production. He also triggered a backfill to update all existing company pages. That's about 50% completed so you should see the fix in the next hour or so.

Thanks for the heads up and our apologies for the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Backfill completed and fix confirmed

Comment: It makes me really happy that SE takes all these "PII leaks" with the atmost urgency and fixes them with a matter of a few hours.  (A small part of me makes me want to add some click-baity privacy leak issues into my other normal bug reports as well).